# Hover not being detected on element

Tags: javascript, css, hover

**Picture:**

[image: problem depicting picture]

**What I want:**

I want the hover to be registered even when the mouse cursor moves over that blue diamond shaped area in the picture above.

**Problem:**

Whenever I hover over that blue diamond shaped area, which visually appears to the user as a region in `.path_part`, the hover rule `.folder_path .path_part:hover` is not being applied on `.part_part`.

**What I tried:**

Set the `z-index` of `.path_part` to 10000 and that of `.right_arrow` to -1. Still no luck.

[JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/m1pacc6z/)

Comment: You need `position:relative` on elements you want to apply `z-index`. Also change the z-index to 1 instead of -1 https://jsfiddle.net/m1pacc6z/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working [fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/bhye2rkp/)

First of all, `z-index` can have a maximum value of 9999.

One thing to note is that only the left portion `.right-arrow` is overlapping with `.path-part`, and since the hover handler is on `.path-part` only that left portion will trigger the hover handler.

Also, for `z-index` to work both `.path-part` and `.right-arrow` need to be positioned, that is, position property set to either `relative`, `absolute` or `fixed`.

Change your CSS to:

```
.folder_path .right_arrow {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 35px;
    width: 35px;
    content: "";
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right     bottom, from(transparent), color-stop(0.5, transparent), color-stop(0.5, #000000), to(#000000));
    margin-left: -25px;    
}

.folder_path .path_part {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    min-width: 40px;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: I think there's something wrong with the fiddle link.  It's not working for me in chrome, I hover over the arrow and the item before it does not light up

Comment: Thats because only the left portion of the arrow is overlapping with the path part which has the hover handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(".path_part").hover(function(){
       $(this).next().css({"background": "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)"});
  }, function(){
       $(this).next().css({"background": "unset"});
  });
```

You can use jquery.This code will work for you.